# How to get NSArray key value as NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have a many NSArray's like so but im not sure how to get the key values of each array like `Boots` or `Dress Shoes`

EDIT: Im not trying to get the values of `Boots` im trying to get the keys `Boots`, `Dress Shoes` etc. not whats inside them.

```
 test {
    Boots =     (
        Brogue,
        Chelsea,
        Chukka,
        Dress,
        "Rain/Snow",
        Rugged
    );
    "Dress Shoes" =     (
        Oxfords,
        "Formal Shoes"
    );
    "Loafers/Slip-ons" =     (
        "Slip-ons",
        Loafers
    );
    Sandals =     (
        "Flip Flops",
        Slides
    );
    Sneakers =     (
        "Low Top",
        "High Tops",
        "Running Shoes",
        "Slip-ons"
    );
}
```

How do i get the value's `Boots`,`Dress Shoes`,etc?

Comment: If you want to be able to access them by name, you'd be better to store it in an NSDictionary. If not, then you'll want to use `NSArray.objectAtIndex`

Comment: I tried `objectAtIndex:indexPath.row` for a UITableView and it had crashed

Comment: @brandonscript you may of misunderstood, I'm not trying to get whats inside "Boots" im trying to get the key "Boot"s itslef

Comment: Figured it out by using NSDictionary and then using an array to call `allKeys`

Comment: for (NSArray *array in test) {
} or use NSArray*keys=[test allKeys];

Comment: Post some code about how your NSArray is initialized?

Comment: Post your code json conversion and array intialization

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provide correct JSON response . I used your above JSON to create a local one in my project and used it parsing

Please find the sample JSON file i used in my project

**Sample.json**

```
{
    "test": {
        "Boots": [
                  "Brogue",
                  "Chelsea",
                  "Chukka",
                  "Dress",
                  "Rain/Snow",
                  "Rugged"
                  ],
        "Dress Shoes": [
                        "Oxfords",
                        "Formal Shoes"
                        ],
        "Loafers/Slip-ons": [
                             "Slip-ons",
                             "Loafers"
                             ],
        "Sandals": [
                    "Flip Flops",
                    "Slides"
                    ],
        "Sneakers": [
                     "Low Top",
                     "High Tops",
                     "Running Shoes",
                     "Slip-ons"
                     ]
    }
}
```

I used below code to get array value . There are two approaches to parse and get array values.

**Approach 1**

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sample" ofType:@"json"];

    NSError * error;
    NSString *fileContents = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error reading file: %@",error.localizedDescription);
    }

    NSDictionary *dataList = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[fileContents dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:NULL];

    NSLog(@"%@",dataList);
    NSDictionary *sourceData = [dataList objectForKey:@"test"];
    NSArray * boots = [sourceData objectForKey:@"Boots"];
    NSArray * shoes = [sourceData objectForKey:@"Dress Shoes"];
    NSArray * loafers = [sourceData objectForKey:@"Loafers/Slip-ons"];
    NSArray * sandals = [sourceData objectForKey:@"Sandals"];
    NSArray * sneakers = [sourceData objectForKey:@"Sneakers"];

    NSLog(@"\n %@ \n %@ \n %@ \n %@ \n %@",boots,shoes,loafers,sandals,sneakers);
```

**Approach 2**

```
 NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sample" ofType:@"json"];

        NSError * error;
        NSString *fileContents = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

        if(error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error reading file: %@",error.localizedDescription);
        }

        NSDictionary *dataList = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[fileContents dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:NULL];

        NSLog(@"%@",dataList);
        NSDictionary *sourceData = [dataList objectForKey:@"test"];

NSArray *keyValues = [sourceData allKeys];

    for (int i =0 ; i < keyValues.count; i++) {
        NSArray *innerContents = [sourceData objectForKey:[keyValues objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSLog(@"%@ \n", innerContents);
    }
```